# Linking Containers via Docker Remote API

Tags: docker

I'm trying to link a child mongo container to a parent node container using the Docker remote API v1.7.

I see the `Links` property in HostConfig which I'm guessing is passed to the
`POST /containers/<id>/start` request like

```
{
  "Links": ["<container-name>:<alias>", ...]
}
```

I don't see how to name the mongo container to use when starting the node container. Is there an API analogy to the CLI `-name` flag for `docker run`?

Do I need to make a separate `GET /containers/<id>/json` request and live with the auto-generated name?

Comment: This will not really answer your question, but whenever I'm wondering "how the hell do I do that with the API", I just sniff the communications between the docker cli and the API. I use tcpflow or socat for that, depending on whether the docker daemon listens over (respectively) tcp or a socket.

Answer (score 9):

In the current (1.8) API, the `-name` flag is passed as a query string to `POST /v1.8/containers/create` – i.e. like this:

```
POST /v1.8/containers/create?name=redis_ambassador
```

(POST body left out for brevity)

I figured this out by using [Geoffrey Bachelet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227887/geoffrey-bachelet)'s excellent suggestion of using socat as a proxy for all of my docker CLI commands using the following commands:

```
# on one terminal  
sudo socat -t100 -v UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/proxysocket.sock,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock

# on a second terminal  
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///tmp/proxysocket.sock"
```

Subsequent `docker` cli commands will be proxied through socat and their CLI calls will be displayed on the other terminal

Comment: The socat proxy is awesome, thanks to you and [Geoffrey Bachelet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/227887/geoffrey-bachelet) for the tip!